# SQL Server : copy rows to another table without duplicate keys

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL issue that's kept me busy for a couple of days now. All I want is to copy most rows from one table (ORIGIN) to another (DESTINATION), but, in DESTINATION there should not be rows with the same PRIMARY KEY. It is possible that in ORIGIN we will have many duplicates at a given moment. Well, so far so good, we have many methods for this and they always worked for me in MySQL (which is what I have always worked with). But now I am forced to use SQL  Server 2008.

So far I have tried the NOT EXIST, NOT IN and JOIN methods. I doesn't matter what I do, I always get the infamous dupe key error. For example, If I use this:

```
insert into DESTINATION 
   select * 
   from ORIGIN 
   where ORIGIN.[MY-PRIMARY-KEY-FIELD] not in
        (select [MY-PRIMARY-KEY-FIELD] from DESTINATION)
```

Then I get this:

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__DESTINAT__52F5604C11CBEE86'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.DESTINATION'. The duplicate key value is (00013884880195).

The specified value is, of course, duplicated in ORIGIN, but that's why I am checking if it also exists in DESTINATION before inserting it. I get the same exact error message with the other methods. Nothing works.

The only thing I can think of is that, maybe, this is threading or doing weird stuff so that the rows are not still there when we go checking for it. Is there a way to force some kind of "synchronous mode" so that the info is pushed into the table as soon as possible to ensure the data is there when we go checking for it? That'd be a simple way to discard that...

Or maybe I am bypassing something silly here. I don't know. So, any hint on what might be happening here will be welcome.

Thanks beforehand.

Comment: Try with group by PK and having count(*)  =1

Comment: If origin has three rows with the same "my-primary-key-field" values, what one row should be inserted into destination?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably this one is more better option..

```
insert into DESTINATION 
Select * from (
select <column_list>,
row_number() over (partition by PK order by PK ) as rnm
from origin)Temp
where rnm=1;
```

Comment: This worked in combination with not in/not exists. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` in query to find records that do not match

```
INSERT INTO DESTINATION  (colfk,col1, col2, col3)
SELECT * FROM (SELECT coppiesfk,coppiesRow1, coppiesRow2, coppiesRow3) AS tmp
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT colfk FROM DESTINATION  WHERE colfk = coppiesfk
) LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are checking that `DESTINATION` doesn't already have `ID` from `ORIGIN`, but if `ORIGIN` has two rows with the same `ID` that doesn't exist in `DESTINATION`, then both rows would be inserted => duplicate key.

One possible variant - add `DISTINCT`.

```
insert into DESTINATION 
select DISTINCT * 
from ORIGIN 
where ORIGIN.[MY-PRIMARY-KEY-FIELD] not in
(select [MY-PRIMARY-KEY-FIELD] from DESTINATION)
```

Comment: I tried this, but, because of something other person did, sometimes the duplicates are not exactly equal in all fields. The primary keys are reliable though, so I used anwaar_hell's tip below. Thanks for the suggestion though. :)